# Page break the data but keep the groups on the same page

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-tablix

I am grouping the data in my table by person and term. I am trying to separate term groupings but keep them on the same page and have only one person per page. This image shows how it looks in Crystal Reports. The only issue I am having with SSRS is that it is putting each term group on a new page.
[Crystal Reports output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td2DF.jpg)
[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnDVH.jpg)

Comment: WIthout seeing the report design it's hard to say but I would guess you have a row group that groups by both person and term with a page break set between the group. You need two separate row groups, the inner one by term and the outer one by person, then only have page breaks on the outer group. If this does not help, show your report design including row groups and their properties

Comment: This worked. It separated the terms with borders instead of whitespace like Crystal Reports, but I'll take what I can get. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I'll add this as an answer so yo can mark it accepted, otherwise the question will look unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the report design it's hard to say but I would guess you have a row group that groups by both person and term with a page break set between the group.

You need two separate row groups, the inner one by term and the outer one by person, then only have page breaks on the outer group.

If this does not help, show your report design including row groups and their properties